# Ubuntu 14.04 login loop, cant use cmd prompt

Tags: 14.04, dual-boot, login-screen

after being away from my computer all summer i decided to boot up ubuntu yesterday and was faced with with the dreaded login loop. Its happened before to me but i was able to bring up the prompt (ctrl-alt-f1), but this time it is not possible. Ive tried logging in through terminal on a guest login but it either closes the terminal or tells me my credentials als are invalid. The problem is most likely associated with my graphic card (gtx 960). Im only assuming this because i also get a black boot up unless boot with nomodeset enabled. Any help would be greatly appreciated! And before someone asks, theres aboout a terabyte of space left in my partition. Im typing this from my phone so i apologize about any grammar or spelling errors. Im also dualbooted with base win7. The graphics card hasnt been swapped either.

Answer (score 0):

My problem was solved with this

```
sudo apt-get purge nvidia*
```

On my other dual-boot device I had problems with secure boot. If it is enabled, then disable it.

Comment: While this would solve my issue, i do not have root access. I do have access to a guest terminal but its not possible to do most anything on it.